# Akoya Touchpad not working

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad

I have Medion Akoya E7226 notebook, with an synaptics touchpad and Kunbuntu installed.
But whatever I try, the touchpad can not be installed because according to the operating system no touchpad is present.
There is no option in the BIOS to switch it on and off.
Anyone have an idea?

cheers

Answer (score 3):

## Getting Touchpad work on Akoya E7226

I've installed such a notebook and had the same problem. The reason is that this notebook uses a 8042 chip for touchpad communication, which is not supported by the kernel per default.

You have to modify your Grub file

- Make a backup of your grub file:

  ```
   sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
  ```
- Edit your grub file:

  ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Now add the following paramters into the line starting with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT**:

  ```
    i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1 i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
  ```

  In my case this line looks like

  ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash logo.nologo i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1 i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
  ```

  Save the changes.
- Now you have to update your grub via

  ```
    sudo update-grub
  ```
- Reboot your machine

Comment: great answer +1